# Add new attribute to existing PLSQL Type with default value without affecting existing calls

Tags: sql, plsql, types

I have the below code snippet where i am creating a type with 2 attributes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE test_params IS OBJECT (
   F_days           number,
   F_comments   VARCHAR2 (100)
   
);
/
```

I am using the above type as below

```
Declare 
    tp test_params;
    tp1 test_params;
BEGIN 
    tp:= test_params(1,'asd');
    tp.f_days:=1;
   dbms_output.put_line(tp.f_days); 
END;
```

It prints 1

Now if I want to add 1 more attribute comments varchar(50) to my type and I dont want to disturb the above code and i want the above output.

Kindly guide me on this

Answer (score 1):

You can create a constructor with optional third argument, then your code will keep working.

```
create or replace 
type test_params is object (
   f_days       number,
   f_comments   varchar2 (100),
   comments     varchar2(50),

   constructor function test_params(
       f_days     number,
       f_comments varchar2,
       comments   varchar2 default null
   ) return self as result
);

create or replace
type body test_params
as
   constructor function test_params(
       f_days     number,
       f_comments varchar2,
       comments   varchar2 default null
   ) return self as result
   as
   begin
       self.f_days := f_days;
       self.f_comments := f_comments;
       self.comments := comments;
       return;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: There are many dependencies to the existing TYPE like 
```CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE varray_test_params is varray(20) of test_params;```
is there any way to create/replace without deleting these dependencies.

Comment: you can try [FORCE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/type-dependencies.html#GUID-C4E930C1-BEE0-43DC-9C32-C0D6B9FDF3A3)

`CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t1 FORCE AS OBJECT (....)`